# Class "MenuModel" not Found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I get this error when i try to run my Laravel

> Class 'Menumodel' not found 
>   in HasRelationships.php (line 487)

Here is my data structure

[image]

And this is `MainComposer.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Menumodel as menu;

class MainComposer
{
    public $items = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->items = menu::tree();
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('items', end($this->items));
    }
}
```

MenuModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Menumodel extends Model
    {
        //
         public $table = 'Menu';
         protected $fillable = ['MenuParent','MenuName','MenuPath','MenuIcon','MenuOrder','RouteName'];

         public function parent() {
            return $this->hasOne('Menumodel', 'MenuCode', 'MenuParent');
        }
        public function children() {
            return $this->hasMany('Menumodel', 'MenuParent', 'MenuCode');
        }  
        public static function tree() {
            return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 4, 'children')))->where('MenuParent', '=', NULL)->get();
        }

    }
```

I aldredy try this use `\App\Menumodel as menu;` but still no different. How can i fix it ?

Comment: What is (at least the first few lines of) the code in `Menumodel.php`?

Comment: @Bytewave I've update my question. sorry about that

Comment: Free advice: Use a decent PHP IDE which would save you load of time running into nitty witty errors like these. Many IDE's has Laravel support now. I personally like PHP-Storm.

Comment: @kisanme is it free ? because i'm still in school

Comment: @YVS1102 https://www.jetbrains.com/student/ especially for students :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are incorrect. You need to provide the full class namespace.

```
return $this->hasOne(Menumodel::class, '...', '...');
return $this->hasMany(Menumodel::class, '...', '...');
```

I've also removed your local and foreign keys because if using Laravel, these are typically snake_case, not StudlyCase, so you may need to double check those too.